# Splitting an object dtype column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My DF look like having multiple delimiters ( , = ) and a combination of int and str.

DF type is object ( not converting to string )

info in the cell of a column contains this info

```
Network=115,MEID=115,Function=115,Area=1806
```

I want to split it using delimiter "=" to get the area info . Is there any way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be generic that the `Area=xxxx` can be anywhere in the cells, we can use [`str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) together with regex (regular expression), as follows:

```
df['Area'] = df['Col1'].str.extract(r'Area=(?P<Area>[^,=]*)')
```

### Test Run

**Test data construction:**

```
data = {'Col1': ['Network=115,MEID=115,Function=115,Area=1806', 'Network=120,MEID=116,Area=1820,Function=116']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

                                          Col1
0  Network=115,MEID=115,Function=115,Area=1806
1  Network=120,MEID=116,Area=1820,Function=116
```

**Run new code**

```
df['Area'] = df['Col1'].str.extract(r'Area=(?P<Area>[^,=]*)')

print(df)


                                          Col1  Area
0  Network=115,MEID=115,Function=115,Area=1806  1806
1  Network=120,MEID=116,Area=1820,Function=116  1820
```

**Regex Explanation:**

`Area=`   to match the parameter `Area=` literally

`(?P<Area>`   name the regex capturing group as `Area`

`[^,=]*`  0 or more occurrence(s) of character class `[^,=]` which matches characters not equals to `,` or `=`

`)`   end of named capturing group

Comment: Great, This is exactly what required.. Thanks a lot